# Click to GitHub repository from a Webpage

Tags: html, github, onclick

Is there a way to click a button on our webpage and it will bring the user back to our GitHub page to show repository information?

This is a group project, trying to have a click event at the bottom of the webpage that would take a viewer back to GitHub to check out the code/ReadMe/etc.

Possible?

Comment: you mean a normal html link <a href>, not? Which sure can be shaped as a button if requires

Comment: Yes you can do just provide href with URL of Github repo and repo must be public

Comment: Great! The public aspect was the hangup - thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to add a button, which should have the link of the Github repository you want to get to.

Something like this:

```
<button>
    <a href="https://github.com/"> Go to your Github Repo </a>
</button>
```

Not sure if this is what you need.

PS. You can add style to your button, by using any CSS library, or your own class.